# What does the jQuery() function do?

Tags: jquery

In continuation to the question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452380/good-jquery-interview-questions-closed

I have a follow up question.
What does the jQuery() function do? (there are four answer to this; subject should at least describe the selector-and-element-set mode)

I tried with googling but could not get a clear answer.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the the source code of *core.js* (http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js).

Comment: What *doesn't* the jQuery() function do? Don't forget `$(Number n)` (makes n cups of tea) and `$($KITCHEN_SINK)`. (Personally I strongly dislike this deeply ambiguous interface.)

Answer (score 1):

The `jQuery` function can handle several types of input:

- *`$("")`, `$(null)`, or `$(undefined)`*
- *`$(DOMElement)`*
- *`$(html)` -> `$(array)`*
- *`$("#id")`*
- *`$("TAG")`*
- *`$(expr, $(...))`*
- *`$(expr, context)`*
- *`$(function)`*

Take a look at the [source code of `jQuery` and `jQuery.fn.init`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) respectively to see how these are handled.

Answer (score 1):

It does different things depending on what you pass to it:

```
jQuery(String query [, DOMElement context])
jQuery(String query [, jQueryResultSet context])
```

This will read the string as a query (eg: `#foo > .bar a`). It will be run in the context of `context` if it is specified, otherwise it is taken from `document`.

```
jQuery(DOMElement node)
```

This converts the node into a jQuery result set containing that node. This is used mostly when you have a reference to an element (eg: in an event handler) and you wish to perform jQuery functions upon it.

```
jQuery(Function readyHandler)
```

This is a shortcut form of this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(Function readyHandler)
```

Running all your jQuery functions once the document has been loaded is so common, this shortcut was added.

```
jQuery('')
jQuery(null)
```

This selects the document.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article, it might help you: http://simonwillison.net/2007/Aug/15/jquery/ Particularly, look at the "Doing stuff with them" paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

All in this document : http://docs.jquery.com/Core